# Unable to mount OSX 10.8 file share with CIFS from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, file-sharing, cifs, smb

I am trying (and failing) to mount a share hosted on my OSX laptop, onto my Ubuntu 12.04 server. The server is a Vbox vm running on a macbook air.

This is my `/etc/fstab` entry

```
//192.168.56.1/Users/sandfox/code /mnt/hostfs cifs user=sandfox,password=passwordhere,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,noperm,rw
```

and this the output from the Ubuntu when I run `sudo  mount -a -vvvv`

```
mount: fstab path: "/etc/fstab"
mount: mtab path:  "/etc/mtab"
mount: lock path:  "/etc/mtab~"
mount: temp path:  "/etc/mtab.tmp"
mount: UID:        0
mount: eUID:       0
mount: proc already mounted on /proc
mount: spec:  "//192.168.56.1/Users/sandfox/code"
mount: node:  "/mnt/hostfs"
mount: types: "cifs"
mount: opts:  "user=sandfox,password=RebelRepublic85,nounix,ver=2,sec=ntlmssp,noperm,rw"
mount: external mount: argv[0] = "/sbin/mount.cifs"
mount: external mount: argv[1] = "//192.168.56.1/Users/sandfox/code"
mount: external mount: argv[2] = "/mnt/hostfs"
mount: external mount: argv[3] = "-v"
mount: external mount: argv[4] = "-o"
mount: external mount: argv[5] = "rw,user=sandfox,password=passwordhere,nounix,ver=2,sec=ntlmssp,noperm"
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.56.1,unc=\\192.168.56.1\Users,nounix,ver=2,sec=ntlmssp,noperm,ver=1,user=sandfox,prefixpath=sandfox/code,pass=********
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

and here is the output from the OSX machine's `/var/log/system.log`

```
Jul 31 13:33:37 Jamess-MacBook-Air.local digest-service[49237]: digest-request: uid=0
Jul 31 13:33:37 Jamess-MacBook-Air.local digest-service[49237]: digest-request: init request
Jul 31 13:33:37 Jamess-MacBook-Air.local digest-service[49237]: digest-request: init return domain: MACBOOKAIR-FD34 server: JAMESS-MACBOOK-AIR
Jul 31 13:33:37 Jamess-MacBook-Air.local digest-service[49237]: digest-request: uid=0
Jul 31 13:33:37 Jamess-MacBook-Air.local digest-service[49237]: digest-request: init request
Jul 31 13:33:37 Jamess-MacBook-Air.local digest-service[49237]: digest-request: init return domain: MACBOOKAIR-FD34 server: JAMESS-MACBOOK-AIR
Jul 31 13:33:37 Jamess-MacBook-Air.local digest-service[49237]: digest-request: uid=0
Jul 31 13:33:37 Jamess-MacBook-Air.local digest-service[49237]: digest-request: od failed with 2 proto=ntlmv2
Jul 31 13:33:37 Jamess-MacBook-Air.local digest-service[49237]: digest-request: user=MACBOOKAIR-FD34\sandfox
Jul 31 13:33:37 Jamess-MacBook-Air.local digest-service[49237]: digest-request kdc: ok user=MACBOOKAIR-FD34\sandfox proto=ntlmv2 flags: 
Jul 31 13:33:37 Jamess-MacBook-Air.local smbd[49120]: MACBOOKAIR-FD34\sandfox connected to path /var/rpc/ncacn_np
```

I realise this early days for problems with OSX but does anyone have any clues? if you need more information, let me know.